# how to change colors in CAD drawing using VBA

Tags: vba, cad

I have an AutoCAD drawing, that's a single line diagram of power system. I want to use VBA for changing colors on it. How to do? Sorry 'bout my English level :). Thank!

Comment: I guess you can only edit Autocad drawaing si .. Autocad? So does Autocad have a VBA editor? Have you opened it yet?

Comment: Yeah AutoCAD has a VBA editor.

Answer (score 1):

This example put in red all the lines in a drawing:

```
Sub color_all_lines()
Dim c As Long
Dim lineObj As AcadLine

For c = 0 To ThisDrawing.ModelSpace.Count - 1
    If ThisDrawing.ModelSpace.Item(c).ObjectName = "AcDbLine" Then
        Set lineObj = ThisDrawing.ModelSpace.Item(c)
        lineObj.color = acRed
    End If
Next c

End Sub
```

If you want to change the Layer (before you have to create a new layer called "layerRED")
then:

```
Sub change_layer()
Dim c As Long
Dim lineObj As AcadLine

For c = 0 To ThisDrawing.ModelSpace.Count - 1
    If ThisDrawing.ModelSpace.Item(c).ObjectName = "AcDbLine" Then
        Set lineObj = ThisDrawing.ModelSpace.Item(c)
        lineObj.layer = "layerRED"
    End If
Next c

End Sub
```

If you want to change layer to all objects:

```
Sub color_all()
Dim c As Long
Dim lineObj As AcadLine

For c = 0 To ThisDrawing.ModelSpace.Count - 1
    Set lineObj = ThisDrawing.ModelSpace.Item(c)
Next c

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of information available.  You will likely need to study up on **AxDbDocument**.

Here is information taken directly from [this](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/visual-basic-customization/edit-blocks-using-objectdbx-in-vba/td-p/6472001) site :

> If you did a search in this forum for "AxDbDocument", or "DBX", you
>   could have found quite a few discussion on the topic of using
>   ObjectDBX to open "side" drawing with AutoCAD (i.e. read drawing into
>   AutoCAD process' memory without opening in AutoCAD editor).
>
> The key step is to create a AxDbDocument and read *.dwg file into it.
>   Then you can access data in the drawing file in the same way as VBA's
>   ThisDrawing object.
>
> Here is a snippet of very simple code of doing it (I use Acad2015,
>   thus the version code (xxxxx.20):
>
> ```
> Option Explicit
>
> Public Sub DbxTest()
>
>     Dim dwgFiles(0 To 1) As String
>     dwgFiles(0) = "C:\Temp\DbxTest01.dwg"
>     dwgFiles(1) = "C:\Temp\DbxTest02.dwg"
>
>     Dim doc As AXDBLib.AxDbDocument
>
>     Dim i As Integer
>
>     For i = 0 To 1
>
>         Set doc = ThisDrawing.Application.GetInterfaceObject("ObjectDBX.AxDbDocument.20")
>         doc.Open dwgFiles(i)
>
>         DoWorkWithDwg doc
>
>     Next
>
> End Sub
>
> Private Sub DoWorkWithDwg(dwg As AXDBLib.AxDbDocument)
>
>     ''MsgBox dwg.Name
>
>     Dim count As Integer
>     Dim ent As AcadEntity
>     For Each ent In dwg.ModelSpace
>         ''MsgBox ent.ObjectName
>         count = count + 1
>     Next
>
>     MsgBox "Drawing: " & dwg.Name & vbCrLf & "Entity Count: " & count
>
> End Sub
> ```

Comment: Thank for your answers very much! I'll try :)

Comment: You're welcome. Be sure to share what you learn in when researching how to accomplish this task, so that others can also benefit from your efforts!  That's the kind of 2-way support that makes Stack Overflow such a gem.  Have you had a chance to check out the [tour]?  There are some other handy tips on pages like [ask] and [mcve].